# Python MongoDB consulta con variables

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, mongoatlas

Espero que me podáis ayudar. Estoy tratando de hacer una consulta usando operadores, esta vez $and y variables. La idea es que mediante un script de python me saque los datos que tengo alojados en una base de datos en MongoDB Atlas con los datos que solicito en consola. El caso es que tengo problemas al escribir el código de consulta en el script de python.

Codigo:

```
elif Sel_user_ini == '4':
            TipRes = input('Elige el tipo de respuesta(true/false)')
            nSeg = input('Numero de Seguidores')
            id_usuario_change = db.Entradas_chicas_IG.find({ "$and": [{"Seguidores": { "$gte": nSeg}},{"Respuesta" : + "''" + TipRes + "''"}]})
            print(id_usuario_change)
            for documento in id_usuario_change :
                print(documento)
```

Trato de concatenar '' al princio y al final '' para que me lo pille como string (asi esta definido en la BBDD) pero algo esta fallando que me da el error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\Con_MonAtlan_IG.py", line 58, in <module>
    id_usuario_change = db.Entradas_chicas_IG.find({ "$and": [{"Seguidores": { "$gte": nSeg}},{"Respuesta" : + "''" + TipRes + "''"}]})
TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str'
```

Podéis orientarme en el problema?

Gracias y un saludo

Comment: Tienes un signo `+` de sobra en: `{"Respuesta" : + "''" + TipRes + "''"}`. Justo después de `"Respuesta":`. Debería ser: `{"Respuesta" : "''" + TipRes + "''"}`. Aunque no entiendo el porqué deseas usar esas dobles comillas de esa manera para envolver tu cadena. Saludos

Comment: Porque tengo definido el campo TipRes  en la BBDD de mongodb como string por tanto entiendo que le debo concatenar comillas. Igualmente tras la consilta no me esta devolviendo nada y me imprime solo el cursor.